# ElasticSearch- [exists] query does not support in elastic search 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

```
POST /ankita-inex/my_type/_bulk

{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "title": "The quick brown fox" }

{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{ "title": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" }

{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{ "title": "The quick brown fox jumps over the quick dog" }

{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{ "title": "Brown fox brown dog" }
```

This gets succesfully posted but i wanted to use exists query for usingMissingQuery

```
GET /ankita-inex/my_type/_search
{
"query" : {

    "bool": {

        "must": {

           "exists" : {

               "index" : "4" 
           }
        }

    }
} }


{

"error": 
 {

  "root_cause": [

     {

        "type": "query_parsing_exception",

        "reason": "[exists] query does not support [index]",

        "index": "ankita-inex",

        "line": 6,

        "col": 20

     }

  ],

  "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",

  "reason": "all shards failed",

  "phase": "query",

  "grouped": true,

  "failed_shards": [

     {

        "shard": 0,

        "index": "ankita-inex",

        "node": "pbwST3JVSlq3sPqBgWoAVg",

        "reason": {

           "type": "query_parsing_exception",

           "reason": "[exists] query does not support [index]",

           "index": "ankita-inex",

           "line": 6,

           "col": 20

        }

     }

  ]

},

"status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exists` query is to find documents having a given named field, not for checking the exact value. If you have to see if document with `_id: 4` exists, you can do it like this:

```
POST /ankita-inex/my_type/_search
{
"query" : {

    "bool": {

        "must": {

           "term" : {

               "_id" : "4" 
           }
        }

    }
} }
```

Or simply like this:

```
GET /ankita-inex/my_type/4
```

This will return the document if it exists

Comment: With this document how can i use MissingQuery for elastic saerch 2.3.If any example

Comment: What do you want to achieve with a MissingQuery?

Comment: Actually i am upgrading application from elastic search 1.4.3 to elastic search 2.3.5 .. Now Elastic Saerch has removed all FilterClasses and merged it into Query.So i want the alternative api for this line  MissingFilterBuilder incProductsEmptyFilter = FilterBuilders.missingFilter("missingfilter");

Comment: Missing still exists in 2.3.5, it's only removed in ES 5, so you can still use it and it will work. Alternative to Missing is to use MustNot + Exists.

Comment: MissingFilterBuilder is removed . In that place MissingQueryBuilder came bt deprecated since 2.0.0 .So it cannot be used in 2.3.5. I am asking for any alternative if any. Kindly help

Comment: "deprecated" doesn't mean "don't use", it simply means "you can use but you should migrate whenever you can". MissingQuery is [still available in 2.3.5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-missing-query.html). As I said, the alternative is to use ExistsQuery in a MustNotQuery